# How can I reduce execution time for a loop that runs for 480,000 iterations?

Tags: visual-studio, loops, runtime, c++17

I am writing some data on a bitmap file, and I have this loop to calculate the data which runs for 480,000 times according to each pixel in 800 * 600 resolution, hence different arguments (coordinates) and different return value at each iteration which is then stored in an array of size 480,000. This array is then used for further calculation of colours.

All these iterations combined take a lot of time, around a minute at runtime in Visual Studio (for different values at each execution). How can I ensure that the time is greatly reduced? It's really stressing me out.

Is it the fault of my machine (i5 9th gen, 8GB RAM)? Visual Studio 2019? Or the algorithm entirely? If it's the algorithm, what can I do to reduce its time?

Here's the loop that runs for each individual iteration:

```
int getIterations(double x, double y) //x and y are coordinates
{
    complex<double> z = 0; //These are complex numbers, imagine a pair<double>
    complex<double> c(x, y);

    int iterations = 0;

    while (iterations < max_iterations) // max_iterations has to be 1000 to get decent image quality
    {
        z = z * z + c;

        if (abs(z) > 2) // abs(z) = square root of the sum of squares of both elements in the pair
        {
            break;
        }

        iterations++;
    }

    return iterations;
}
```

Comment: How does `*`, `+`, or `abs()` works for your complex numbers?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep It's from a C++ library 'complex'. It basically evaluates both elements from the pair individually the same way as normal operations would and stores them in z.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, this loop is to run 48k times. The doubles x and y are coordinates for the bitmap, so they are always unique.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't know about release mode or the optimisation setting. I am still a beginner and I only know about the STL and such other libraries like vectors, memory, assert. It's my first project too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am writing on the file, not gaining information from it. The return value determines what color to give to each pixel. How it is to be colored is in another function, but that takes only half a second according to function profiling I did while debugging.

Comment: @ChaitanyaDSingh See more ideas at [Optimizing Mandelbrot fractal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354589/optimizing-mandelbrot-fractal).

Comment: @dxiv I'll definitely check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how exactly your `abs(z)` works, but based on your description, it might be slowing down your program by a lot.

Based on your description, your are taking the sum of squares of both element of your complex number, then get a square root out of it. Whatever your methods of square root is, it probably takes more than just a few lines of codes to run.

Instead, just compare `complex.x * complex.x + complex.y * complex.y > 4`, it's definitely faster than getting the square root first, then compare it with 2

Comment: I'll certainly give it a try.

Comment: There's no change in speed even after trying this method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason the above should be done during run-time?

I mean: the result of this loop seems dependant only on "x" and "y" (which are only coordinates), thus you can try to constexpr-ess all these calculation to be done at compile-time to pre-made a map of results...

At least, just try to build that map once during run-time initialisation.

Comment: Well you see, the algorithm is to be used in a GUI so that when someone clicks on a coordinate the image zooms (there's a zoom algorithm which will recreate the zoomed part - you can search for a fractal viewer to get the idea). So I need to run the algorithm at run time.

Comment: But the inputs are (despite being `double`s) fixed: if normalized, they can be `int`s. And then you can then pre-multiply your coord to make them normalized, call that function and recalculate the results. Another hint may be that the number of `iterations` is a logarithm: you're searching a number (`iterations`) which is the exponent of abs(z)^X < 2. So you can try replacing the inner loop with a log.